# Torque of centripetal force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque, centripetal-force

Suppose there is a particle of mass $m$ attached on the rim of an accelerating wheel. At any particular point, there should be a centripetal force passing through the IAOR, will this force apply torque about the center of the wheel?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I think that it should have a torque but i am not sure

Comment: @BioPhysicist I think it applies a torque that causes the circular motion. Isn't circular motion just rotation about an axis outside the body?

Answer (score 0):

Torque is produced when couple force acts on the body which changes its angular acceleration and centripetal force only has angular velocity as it is not changing how much fast it rotates with time  (because of uniform circular motion).
Simply change in angular momentum is torque and centripetal force does not change angular momentum so both are different and it does not produce a torque

Comment: or simply by formulae , centripetal force always acts towards the centre and the displacement vector always acts in the same or opposite direction to the centripetal force which makes an angle of 0 or 180 degrees , when seen for the formulae for torque , it would give sin0 or sin180 which would make the torque 0 hence centripetal force can never create a torque

Answer (score 0):

No. By definition of torque,
$$ |\vec \tau| = |\vec r\times \vec F| =  rF \sin(\theta)$$

centripetal forces are always collinear to a rotating point position vector $\vec r$, hence $\sin(0^\circ)=0$ and so any form of centripetal force (or even it's counterpart - centrifugal force) do not induce any torque, because they act only in radial directions perpendicular to tangential directions where torque is maximum.